# How can you find the whole number of a given decimal or other number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to do some calculations as follows in JavaScript:

1. If result of a division is 0.02 final result should be 1
2. If result of a division is 1.2 final result should be 2
3. If result of a division is 2.05 final result should be 3

Comment: I don't understand your logic...

Comment: use [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

Comment: Oh I see now, you want to know the number of decimals and fill with zero if needed right?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you're looking for [`Math.ceil`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.6):

```
var ceilResult = Math.ceil(resultOfDivision);
```

E.g.:

```
console.log(Math.ceil(0.02)); // "1"
console.log(Math.ceil(1.2));  // "2"
console.log(Math.ceil(2.05)); // "3"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the Math.ceil() function ([see the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil))

Quoting from the doc :

*The following example shows example usage of Math.ceil() :*

```
Math.ceil(.95); // 1
Math.ceil(4); // 4
Math.ceil(7.004) // 8
```